# nslookup script problemas con subcomandos!

Tags: script

Necesito realizar un miniscript para automatizar este proceso introducido manualmente:

```
nslookup
>server ns1.server.com
>ls ejemplo.com
```

Necesito guardar todas las salidas del ls en un txt o csv.

El caso es que no encuentro ninguna forma de automatizar estos 3 pasos en uno. Y he probado en todo en powershell, bash... y nada. No he podido probar en python u otro lenguaje ya que el server no tiene acceso a internet para poder descargar librerias correspondientes.

Me gustaría hacer algo con esta forma nslookup ls ejemplo.com ns1.server.com > ejemplo.txt

Pero no hay manera alguna, help me pls.

Saludos

Comment: nslookup /server ns1.server.com /ls ejemplo.com

Comment: nslookup /server ns1.server.com /ls ejemplo.com  eso no funciona . Ojalá fuese así.

Comment: Huh... tiene razón.  Bueno, no es porque no leí la documentación. Lo encontré aqui https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/nslookup (en inglés)